# I need the drivers for Sony DSC-HX300 camera

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, camera

I've bought today Sony DSC-HX300 camera and don't have the drivers for Windows XP. I've checked the internet and haven't found it.

Where can I find it?

Comment: I found them without a problem.  They are on the Sony website.

Answer (score 0):

on the website.
perhaps you didn't click "open file list" to get the file showing as below

http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=DSCHX300&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=download#/downloadTab

[image]

Comment: Please don't answer obviously off topic questions.